# How to put the res files from the project to the jar in the same folder?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, kotlin

I have problem with gradle. 
I need the res folder had exactly the same location as in the project in order that would be executable file addressed to the resource in the same way as in the "unbuild" project.
my project file tree:

```
Project
+--src
   +--main
      |--kotlin
      +--res
```

In the project resource usage I address in the following way:

```
var serviceAccount =  FileInputStream("src/main/res/my_resource_file.json")
```

And I need when assembled the project location of the resource file saved in the jar file

my build.gradle file:

```
group 'Bot'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    jsoup = "1.10.2"
    //...
    firebase_admin = "5.0.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    //...
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:$firebase_admin"
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/res"]
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.my.bot.MainKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

I suspect that you need to configure this section `jar{//...}`, but i don't know what did is in gradle

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would reference such as resource from: `src/main/resources` as the source folder which then is copied auto copied into your JAR by Gradle.  You then use the Classloader to read the resources as a stream.

If I placed a file at `src/main/resources/my_resource_file.json` it would be loaded via:

```
// relative to the current class package location
val input  = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/my_resource_file.json")

// or use system classloader
val input = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_resource_file.json")
```

You are instead doing it in a non standard way by using `res` as the directory name instead of `resources` and by trying to access it as a file instead of a classpath resource.  In Gradle docs (similarly for Maven) they explain the file layout: [Gradle Java Project Layout](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout)